# Is a local copy of install.wim required?

Tags: windows-7

I installed Windows 7 using the network boot option, and today realized that the install.wim file is still present on my hard disk.

Is there any viable situation in which I need it? How safe would it be to remove it? The file is around 4GB in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say Yes, this is OK to delete. If this is not the first time the computer has had Windows installed on it there may be a Windows.old folder in the root of C:\ drive which will also be OK to delete (bear in mind you might want to sift through and see if there is anything useful in there before deletion).